# How to separate the polygons from Multi polygons in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector, splitting

I have a polygon (Multi polygon) which contain 5 species data. All are shown by its different ranges. I want to separate them because I want to analyze their ranges individually? Is there any way to make separate polygon for each in efficient way because I  need to separate 100 of similar species in one polygon too

I am attaching my Picture of data with attribute table

[image]

**Update 1**

I try to do "split vector layer" it works,  but it save each layer into GPKG file. Is it possible to get result in shape file. Because I need shp. file of each species in my further analysis in R.

**Update 2**

I don't get the option of saving project into .shp and etc in my output directory tab when I do split vector layers. And also in setting I changed the default extension in shapefile but I doesn't work.

Comment: Try `split vector layer`.

Comment: Thanks it works but I updated the problem in Update 1 please check out this. _Erik

Comment: Split vector layer tools has an option `Output file type`.

Comment: There is no option. I only got save to temporary and save to permanent directory. _user30184

Comment: Look at your data attribute table. If you have different colours it looks like you might have some columns with different values, which are distinguishable enough for separation from the main polygon.

Comment: Yes I have able to figure out this problem. Can you look on Update 1 and update 2 -MKR1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Vector** < **Data Management Tool** < **Split Vector Layer**. There is one **Advanced Parameters** Select shp there.